# Preseeding in Ubuntu installer

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iso

I want to run a few commands immediately after installation of Ubuntu.Therefore I thought of using preseeding concept.I extracted my iso and in the preseed folder appended the following line to custom.seed file

d-i preseed/late_command string in-target mkdir /home/abc

Now I repacked the iso and installed ubuntu using it..But no change happened..What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I can't tell you what is wrong with that but I can tell you how I got mine working after lots of trial and error.

My requirements were to package new and replacement files in the ISO, as well as run a script after install.

**preseed file**:

```
d-i preseed/late_command string /bin/sh -c "$(cat /setup.sh); exit 0"
```

No doubt this is an odd way to run a script, but it works.

**setup.sh**:

```
# [ hardware/hosting detection, other customizations ]
# set PackageList string
in-target --pass-stdout /bin/sh -c \
  "apt-get update &&
   apt-get install -y $PackageList &&
   apt-get dist-upgrade -y
  "
```

This script is run in the installer environment that is lost on reboot. You must use the `in-target` command to run in the installed environment.

**existing process to unpack ISO here**

**packing file in initrd**

`initrd` is a filesystem archive that is expanded on boot and the environment the installer runs in. The `setup.sh` file in my case needs to be copied to that archive.

**Expand** `initrd` archive

```
cd $ExpandedISO/install
mkdir initrd
cd initrd
gzip -dc ../initrd.gz | cpio -id --no-absolute-filenames
```

**Copy** new files into expanded `initrd` directory.

**Rebuild** `initrd` archive:

```
# in $ExpandedISO/install/initrd/
find . | cpio -o -H newc | gzip > ../initrd.gz
# expanded dir can now be deleted to not take up space in ISO
rm -rf $ExpandedISO/install/initrd/
```

**Existing process to repack ISO here**